# AWS Codestar -- Build with node.js module dependencies

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I'm using AWS Codestar. It integrates a number of AWS services so that I can go from `git push` to deployment.

It uses cloudformation. I have a lambda function that depends on the `uuid` npm.

How do I include this node dependency in the Codestar build pipeline? Cloudformation SAM use a zip file, and uploads everything to S3:

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/inline_swagger/template.yaml#L32

I don't want to build a zip file and put it into the code repo.

My next plan is to attempt running `npm install` in Codebuild:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-nodejs-hw.html#sample-nodejs-hw-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next plan works. Needed to add the npm in Codebuild. Works great.

Comment: I ran into this again with a long list of modules. I couldn't get the npm install to read from a package.json artifact, so I ended up just typing them all out on one line.

Comment: can you please post your complete answer I want to use pg-promise and I cannot require the module